# Use variable name stored as string within across / mutate computations

Tags: r, tidyverse

This is a contrived example of the problem I'm facing.

I'm trying to perform a computation within `mutate()`/`across()` where one of the column names is stored as a string supplied as an argument to a function. I originally thought I could use `{{col}}` to accomplish this but it does not work here.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

vec_cols <- c('aa','bb')
 
atest <- data.frame(aa = 1:3,
                    bb = rep(0, 3),
                    cc = -(1:3),
                    dd = rep(10,3))
 
map(vec_cols, \(col) atest %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(), .fns = ~ {{col}} * .x)))
```

And that produces the following error:

```
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(.cols = everything(), .fns = ~"aa" * .x)`.
ℹ In row 1.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `aa`.
Caused by error in `"aa" * aa`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

However, I'm able to accomplish this by evaluating the expression using the ol' `eval(parse())` or `get()` tricks. Is there something that's a bit more "tidy" for how this could be done?

```
> map(vec_cols, \(col) atest %>%
+       rowwise() %>%
+       mutate(across(
+         .cols = everything(),
+         .fns = ~ eval(parse(text = col)) * .x
+       )))
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Rowwise: 
     aa    bb    cc    dd
  <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1     0    -1    10
2     4     0    -4    20
3     9     0    -9    30

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Rowwise: 
     aa    bb    cc    dd
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0     0
2     0     0     0     0
3     0     0     0     0

> 
> map(vec_cols, \(col) atest %>%
+       rowwise() %>%
+       mutate(across(
+         .cols = everything(),
+         .fns = ~ get(col) * .x
+       )))
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Rowwise: 
     aa    bb    cc    dd
  <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1     0    -1    10
2     4     0    -4    20
3     9     0    -9    30

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Rowwise: 
     aa    bb    cc    dd
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0     0
2     0     0     0     0
3     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: the `get(col)` one is also a good and valid answer! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is `.data[[col]]`- [from the documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#indirection):

> When you have an env-variable that is a character vector, you need to index into the .data pronoun with `[[`, like `summarise(df, mean = mean(.data[[var]]))`.

```
map(vec_cols, \(col) atest |> mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x * .data[[col]])))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
  aa bb cc dd
1  1  0 -1 10
2  4  0 -4 20
3  9  0 -9 30

[[2]]
  aa bb cc dd
1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to loop through the subset data:

```
map(atest[vec_cols], ~atest*.x)
$aa
  aa bb cc dd
1  1  0 -1 10
2  4  0 -4 20
3  9  0 -9 30

$bb
  aa bb cc dd
1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0
```

If you must use mutate, whereby you have some other stuff in there you could do:

```
map(atest[vec_cols], ~mutate(atest,across(everything()) *.x))
```

And if you want to even do some crazy stuff within the across you could do:

```
map(atest[vec_cols], 
   ~mutate(atest, ...1 = .x, across(everything(), ~.x*...1), ...1 = NULL))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

vec_cols <- c('aa', 'bb')

atest <- data.frame(aa = 1:3,
                    bb = rep(0, 3),
                    cc = -(1:3),
                    dd = rep(10, 3))

map(vec_cols, ~ atest %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(across(.cols = everything(), .fns = ~ !!sym(.x) * .x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `eval_tidy()` from `rlang` package:

"`eval_tidy()` is a variant of `base::eval()` that powers the tidy evaluation framework. Like `eval()` it accepts user data as argument..." see `?eval_tidy()`

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

map(vec_cols, \(col) {
  col_sym <- sym(col)
  atest %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ eval_tidy(col_sym) * .x))
})
```

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Rowwise: 
     aa    bb    cc    dd
  <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1     0    -1    10
2     4     0    -4    20
3     9     0    -9    30

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Rowwise: 
     aa    bb    cc    dd
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0     0
2     0     0     0     0
3     0     0     0     0
```